# Python; argparse; how to specify position of positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

How do I specify the position of a positional argument?

In my example below, the SCR & SCV arguments appear at the end of the optional arguments, I want them to appear at the beginning.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

### Parse arguments ###
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("SCR",type=int)
parser.add_argument("SCV",type=int)
parser.add_argument("--itemid",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--tkt",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--rfc",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--state",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--vendor",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--application",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--submitter",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--assigneddev",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--manager",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--maasteps",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--reasonforfailure",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--assignedpm",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--release",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--erelease",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--testenvloaded",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--datetestloaded",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--dateint2loaded",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--tqadeploytime",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--prodenvloaded",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--dateprodloaded",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--proddeploytime",nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("--proddeployer",nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()



> scratch.py -h
usage: scratch.py [-h] [--itemid [ITEMID]] [--tkt [TKT]] [--rfc [RFC]]
                  [--state [STATE]] [--vendor [VENDOR]]
                  [--application [APPLICATION]] [--submitter [SUBMITTER]]
                  [--assigneddev [ASSIGNEDDEV]] [--manager [MANAGER]]
                  [--maasteps [MAASTEPS]]
                  [--reasonforfailure [REASONFORFAILURE]]
                  [--assignedpm [ASSIGNEDPM]] [--release [RELEASE]]
                  [--erelease [ERELEASE]] [--testenvloaded [TESTENVLOADED]]
                  [--datetestloaded [DATETESTLOADED]]
                  [--dateint2loaded [DATEINT2LOADED]]
                  [--tqadeploytime [TQADEPLOYTIME]]
                  [--prodenvloaded [PRODENVLOADED]]
                  [--dateprodloaded [DATEPRODLOADED]]
                  [--proddeploytime [PRODDEPLOYTIME]]
                  [--proddeployer [PRODDEPLOYER]]
                  SCR SCV
```

Comment: In traditional UNIX programs, options (what argparse calls "optional arguments") come before operands ("positional arguments").  Most modern programs will accept them in either order, but argparse still encourages people to pass them correctly.  Why do you want to defeat that?

Comment: Optional arguments *always* come before positional arguments in command line interfaces. Why do you need this to be different?

Comment: i just thought it 'reads' better with the required arguments first rather than last...

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments

Comment: 4480075 asks about making positionals optional, this asks about position in the usage line.  Not a duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Always? Git has them come after.

Comment: @user1175849: fine, *good* command line interfaces don't break that convention. Git is a terrible command-line UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `usage` formatter separates the positional arguments from the optionals, and displays them at the end.  In the case of multiline displays like this, the positionals are put on a separate line.  That is what you are seeing.

When parsing positionals can come first.

An obvious way around this is to supply your own usage string, but with this many arguments I can understand not wanting to do so.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26986546/901925
(last November) has a `HelpFormatter` patch that disables this reordering.  But as written it only applies to single line usage.  Multiline usage is handled later in the same method.