# Argparse suggests nonsensical order in help text usage line

Tags: python, parameter-passing, argparse

This program:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('files', metavar='INPUT', nargs='*',
    help='File(s) containing words to include. If none given, stdin will be used.')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--exclude', nargs='*',
    help='File(s) containing words to exclude.')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.files
print args.exclude
```

produces this output when run in Python 2.7.9:

```
$ python prog.py --help
usage: prog.py [-h] [-x [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]]] [INPUT [INPUT ...]]

positional arguments:
  INPUT                 File(s) containing words to include. If
                        none given, stdin will be used.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -x [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]], --exclude [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]]
                        File(s) containing words to exclude.
```

However, that "help" output instructs the user to use a nonsensical ordering for the arguments. It is nonsensical because if the `-x` option is used, then no `INPUT` arguments will be detected.

Argparse ought instead to advise the user to use this ordering:

```
usage: prog.py [-h] [INPUT [INPUT ...]] [-x [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]]]
```

Two questions:

1. Is this a bug in `argparse`? (I think it is.)
2. Regardless of whether it is a bug, how can I fix it so that `$ python prog.py --help` will output the help text I desire (see above), preferably in as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) a way as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the `usage` line, flagged arguments are placed first, positional after.  That fits with common commandline usage.  It makes no effort to evaluate whether that is the best choice or not.

The simplest way around this is to provide a custom `usage` parameter.

(there have be SO questions about changing the order of arguments in the usage line.  The solution requires customization of the `HelpFormatter` class.  [Change argparse usage message argument order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224573/change-argparse-usage-message-argument-order?rq=1)
)

As you note, when the *  positional is placed after the * optional, all arguments are assigned to the optional.  You could use a `'--'` to separate the two lists of arguments.

There is a bug/issue with patch that should improve handling when the `positional` takes a known number of arguments (e.g. the default one). It does so by noting that the positional requires an argument, so it reserves one for it.  But in the `* *` case, the `positional` is satisfied with none, so it has no way of knowing how to split the arguments between the 2.

I like the idea of turning that `postional` into a flagged argument.  That should reduce the ambiguity inherent in lots of `*` arguments.

Comment: The aim of argparse is to reduce the burden on the programmer when (generating help text for) parsing command line arguments. If argparse is going to generate the usage line "automagically", then it should do the right thing by default. By all means let it put flagged arguments first in all cases where that makes sense, but it absolutely should not do that in cases where it would be nonsensical, because that does *not* help the programmer nearly so much. The programmer shouldn't have to fight his/her tools. That's why I think it's a bug. Thanks for answering both my questions, though :)

Comment: You are welcome to submit a patch that corrects this.  The method that generates the usage line is rather long and fragile.  It could use some improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add `usage="..."` to `argparse.ArgumentParser()`.

By viewing the source of argparse, I found a way to resort arguments which might be a little bit dirty:

```
class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):

    def _format_actions_usage(self, actions, groups):
        actions.sort(key=lambda a: bool(a.option_strings and a.nargs != 0))
        return super(MyHelpFormatter, self)._format_actions_usage(actions, groups)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class = MyHelpFormatter)
```

Comment: Thanks. That provides me with an answer to q.2. It's not ideal as it is not DRY: I'll have to update it each time I add/remove arguments. Any thoughts on q.1?

Comment: @sampablokuper: Updated with a way to resort. I think it can be called a bug.

Comment: eph, it's dirty enough that I don't entirely understand (yet?) how it works :) Still, very nice work to have achieved re-ordering of the usage text; and thanks for corroborating!

Answer (score 1):

Add `'-f', '--files'` to the input option:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--files', metavar='INPUT', nargs='*', required=True,
    help='File(s) containing words to include. If none given, stdin will be used.')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--exclude', nargs='*',
    help='File(s) containing words to exclude.')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.files
```

shows:

```
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [-f [INPUT [INPUT ...]]]
                    [-x [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f [INPUT [INPUT ...]], --files [INPUT [INPUT ...]]
                        File(s) containing words to include. If none given,
                        stdin will be used.
  -x [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]], --exclude [EXCLUDE [EXCLUDE ...]]
                    File(s) containing words to exclude.
print args.exclude
```

You can make 'files'  required. From the docs:

> In general, the argparse module assumes that flags like -f and --bar indicate optional arguments, which can always be omitted at the command line. To make an option required, True can be specified for the required= keyword argument to add_argument():

Comment: Just make it required with `required= True`.

Comment: Thanks. `INPUT` is mandatory, which is why I didn't do that in the first place. OTOH, it's true that providing that input from one or more *files* is optional, so maybe I should have done. Hm, I'll think this over again :)