# How to avoid args confusion with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

In a python script called `simulate.py`, I have the following arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--simulators', nargs='+',
                     help='specify the simulators to use',
                     choices=['s1', 's2', 's3'])
parser_build = subparsers.add_parser('build')
parser_build.add_argument('-o3', '--optim', action='store_true')
parser_run = subparsers.add_parser('run')
parser_run.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
```

The following command line options:

```
> ./simulate.py -s s1 s2 build
```

generates the following error message:

```
simulate.py: error: argument -s/--simulators: invalid choice: 'build'
```

How should I specify the simulators list in this case where I have another argument without option prefix (such as -c for exemple) ?

Comment: Have you considered [using docopt](http://docopt.org/)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably what you want is `./simulate.py -s s1 s2 -- build`

Comment: @Joost no, never heard about it. I'll look at it put I prefer stay with argparse if possible.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini this raises an other error `simulate.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: '--' (choose from 'build', 'run')`

Comment: This is a known issue - A variable `nargs` flagged argument followed a positional.  With the complication that this positional is a `subparsers`.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you point me to links discussing the issue and potential way of solving it ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in: [Argparse - do not catch positional arguments with `nargs`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985650/argparse-do-not-catch-positional-arguments-with-nargs)

an `nargs='+'` `optional` (flagged argument) followed by a `positional` has problems.  The `optional` consumes all the strings, leaving none for the `positional`.  There is a proposed bug patch, but it hasn't been released.

The normal quick solution is to use `'--'` to mark the end of the `optional` and its arguments.  Everything else is treated as `positionals`.  You could also put some other flagged argument in between.

What complicates your case is that `-s` takes choices.  And the `positional` is a `subparsers`, which also takes choices, `['build', 'run']`.  As a human you understand 's2' as a choice that belongs to `-s`, and 'build' as one of the parsers.  But `argparse` does not allocate arguments based on choices; it just uses counts (the `nargs`).  `choices` are checked after allocating the arguments.

I'd have to look at the code to see why `'-s s1 s2 -- build'` raises a subparsers choices error.  Normally  '--' is ignored. But apparently `subparsers` is not doing that.  It is a special `positional` Action class.

==========================

I found the code that explains your `'--'` problem.  In a function that converts strings to the `type`, there is a code block:

```
    # for everything but PARSER, REMAINDER args, strip out first '--'
    if action.nargs not in [PARSER, REMAINDER]:
        try:
            arg_strings.remove('--')
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Your `subparsers` argument has `nargs=PARSER`, so the `--` is not removed.

============================

I think you need to change `-s` so it accepts a fixed number of arguments.  Or define some other `optional`, useful or not, that can mark its end.  Feel free to look at the linked bug issue if you want to get into the `argparse` guts.