# Argparse nargs="+" is eating positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

Here's a subsection of my parser configuration

```
parser.add_argument(
    'infile', help="The file to be imported",
    type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin
)

parser.add_argument(
    '--carpark', nargs='+', dest='CarparkID', type=int, default=[],
    help="One or many carpark IDs"
)
```

However, the `--carpark` argument seems to be too greedy and eats *anything* that follows it:

```
$ mycommand --carpark 17 ~/path-to-file
mycommand: error: argument --carpark: invalid int value: '/home/oli/path-to-file'
```

What's a good way around something like this? I need to pass a list of integer IDs into the command but also have a positional file (which can also be stdin).

Is there —for example— a non-greedy `nargs` option that will only parse as much of this as makes sense?

Comment: Note that it doesn't make much sense to specify a default value for a positional argument, since they are not optional.

Comment: @chepner The idea there was to allow me to pipe things into the command as well, instead of doing silly redirects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to specify multiple car park IDs, I would do one of two things instead of using `nargs='+'`:

1. Use the option once per ID (`mycommand --carpark 17 --carpark 18`)

   ```
   parser.add_argument('--carpark',
                       dest='carpark_ids',
                       type=int,
                       action='append',
                       default=[],
                       help="One carpark ID (can be used multiple times)"
   )
   ```
2. Take a single, comma-delimited argument instead (`mycommand --carpark 17,18`)

   ```
   def intlist(s):
       rv = []
       for x in s.split(','):
           try:
               x = int(x)
           except ValueError:
               raise ArgumentTypeError("Non-integer carpark id {x}" % (x,))
           rv.append(x)
       return rv

   parser.add_argument('--carpark',
                       type=intlist,
                       dest='carpark_ids',
                       default=[],
                       help="One or more carpark IDs"
   )
   ```

   With a little more work, you could modify this to allow multiple uses of `--carpark` to accumulate all  its values into a single list.

A third alternative, one I'm not particularly fond of, is to abandon the positional argument, making it an optional argument instead. (`mycommand --carpark 17 18 --infile ~/path-to-file`).

```
parser.add_argument('--infile',
                    help="The file to be imported",
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                    default=sys.stdin
)

parser.add_argument('--carpark',
                    nargs='+',
                    dest='CarparkID',
                    type=int,
                    default=[],
                    help="One or many carpark IDs"
)
```

Comment: Great suggestions.  In python3, for option2, it should be `type=lambda s: list(map(str, s.split(","))),`

Comment: At that point, I would probably switch to `[int(x) for x in s.split(",")]` (which would work in Python 2, but I liked the brevity of using `map`).

Comment: Looking back, I would probably also define a named function (with a type-looking name) like `intlist` rather than using a `lambda`. That would also allow you to raise an `ArgumentTypeError` rather than propagating the `ValueError` if a non-integer value is included in the input.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work?

```
$ mycommand ~/path-to-file --carpark 17
```

---

There is a Python bug/issue over `+` Actions that consume too many arguments, leaving none for following Actions.

The argument allocation is based on argument counts, not on `type`.  The `type` function is applied after allocation, and there's no provision for returning 'rejected' arguments.

In correct behavior it should take into account that `infile` is expecting an argument - and there aren't any further flag strings - and thus reserve one string to that Action.

I could look that bug/issue up, but for now the fix is to supply the arguments in a different order.  Or define a `--infile` action (instead of the positional).

An earlier question, with the bug/issue link (my answer focuses more on getting the `usage` right).

[Argparse - do not catch positional arguments with `nargs`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985650/argparse-do-not-catch-positional-arguments-with-nargs)

Comment: It does but it makes the argument positional. It has to be the last one. In practice there are actually a lot more arguments than I'm letting on and there is another nargs="+" argument that gives the same issue. Needless to say it's impossible to use both arguments together.