# CLI option that is an aggregation of two other options and precedence, in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm using `argparse` to parse CLI options in my Python scripts. I would create a flag that is equivalent to specifying two other flags. So

```
python myscript.py --flagc
```

is equivalent to

```
python myscript.py --flaga --flagb
```

This is my code:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.flagc:
    args.flaga = True
    args.flagb = True
```

The problem is `flaga` and `flagb` have also opposite flags, `no-flaga` and `no-flagb`:

```
parser.add_argument("--flaga", dest="flaga", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--no-flaga", dest="flaga", action="store_false")
parser.set_defaults(flaga=False)
```

and so on. So I could have trouble with flags precedences. For example, if I call the script with:

```
python myscript.py --flagc --no-flaga
```

I get `True` for `args.flaga`, but normally you want `False`, since last flag have precedence.

How can I manage this?

Comment: I suspect you'd have to do this *"by hand"*, rather than relying on `argparse` - I don't think it has a way to express precedence. Or your post-processing could check for e.g. `no-flaga` before setting `flaga` for `flagc`. Or you could make the CLI options less confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, by processing `flag_c` after parsing you loose the precedence information.  Often that issue argues in favor of this post processing, but here a custom Action might be the better choice.

```
class MyAction(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # adapt from _StoreConst
        # leave the self.dest set; could deactivate
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
        setattr(namespace, 'flaga', True)
        setattr(namespace, 'flagb', True)

parser.add_argument("--flagc", action=MyAction)

print(parser.parse_args('--flaga'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args('--flagc'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args('--flagc --no-flaga'.split()))
```

printing:

```
1027:~/mypy$ python stack33264649.py 
Namespace(flaga=True, flagb=False, flagc=False)
Namespace(flaga=True, flagb=True, flagc=True)
Namespace(flaga=False, flagb=True, flagc=True)
```

It's the simplest custom class that does the job.  It takes advantage of the defaults set by its parent (esp. `nargs=0`).  Alternatively it could be based off of `_StoreConst` or even `Action`.

I'm leaving the `setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)` in place.  There's little harm in having an accurate indicator of whether `--flagc` was invoked or not. And it is simpler than trying to suppress `flagc` default.

OK, suppressing the default isn't that hard:

```
class MyAction(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAction, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.default=argparse.SUPPRESS
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, 'flaga', True)
        setattr(namespace, 'flagb', True)
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I suspected you should do something with the Action class, but I didn't know how. Where do you find the documentation about? PS: is it correct to extend a class that is signaled as internal use only? I mean, `_StoreTrueAction` has the underscore at its name start.