# Why does if test fail to work with my parsing arg?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm having a puzzle here trying to figure out what goes on in the machine. This is my code:

```
import argparse, sys
from scitools.StringFunction import StringFunction

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--f', '--function', type=str, default=None,\
                    help='Function', metavar='f')
parser.add_argument('--fn', '--filename', type=str, default=None,\
                    help='Filename', metavar='fn')

args = parser.parse_args()

print args.f and args.fn == None, type(args.fn), type(args.f)

if args.f and args.fn == str:
    f = StringFunction(args.f); filename = args.fn 
else:
    print 'Failed to provide f, filename or both!'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Running: `--f x**2 --fn somename` in terminal.

Now the print statement yields:

```
False <type 'str'> <type 'str'>
```

in my terminal, but the if test gives:

```
Failed to provide f, filename or both!
```

right afterwards! Why does this happen?

Comment: The `type=...` parameter is not the same as the Python function `type()`.  The parameter specifies a function that converts a string into something that you want. You rarely need anything other than `int` or `float`.  `str` works but is unnecessary.   `bool` is wrong  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse/19233287#19233287)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *type* of `args.fn` is `str`, but you test if `args.fn` is *itself* equal to it's type. It can't be both.

You are doing this:

```
>>> type('foo')
<type 'str'>
>>> 'foo' == str
False
```

Use `isinstance()` instead:

```
if args.f and isinstance(args.fn, str):
```

The better test would be to see if `args.fn` is *not `None`*:

```
if args.f and args.fn is not None:
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that solved it and also gave me a better understanding of this type of problem!:)