# argparse doesn't cast default numeric arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Some lines of code are worth a thousand words. Create a python file `test.py` with the following:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--G', type=float, default=1, nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.G / 3)
```

Then, in a terminal:

```
python test.py
```

gives `0`, while:

```
python test.py --G 1
```

gives `0.333333333`. I think this is because `argparse` doesn't seem to cast `default` arguments to their proper type (so `1` remains an `int` in `default=1`, in spite of the `type=float`), but it casts the argument if it is given explicitly.

I think this is inconsistent and prone to errors. Is there a reason why `argparse` behaves this way?

Comment: *You* are deciding on the default value. It's *your* responsibility to be consistent. Why should Python question your decisions? No value was supplied on the command line, you already did supply a default value, why should Python filter it through some function? What if you mean to use `False` as the default value?

Comment: @deceze I don't say there should be a filtering, but an implicit cast. If I decide to pass `False` as default argument, it should be converted to `0.0`. That's only my opinion, of course. I am open to arguments justifying `argparse` current behavior.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a comment.

Comment: That's what I'm arguing: argparse should *not* further modify the default value you have decided on. Because it would restrict what you're able to do. `type` means *filter any input through this function*, but that does not apply when there's no input, because you already have full control over the default value yourself and don't need to further sanitise it.

Comment: default=1.0 does not work?

Comment: @deceze I tried with **'1.0'** (string) instead of 1 for default and it did convert it to float, so I think there is some conversion involved. Not sure why 1 is not being converted.

Comment: @YOU Yes, of course. The point is that it is not obvious that you should not use `$default=1` (since it would could lead to errors, as my example shows).

Answer (score 2):

I think the `1` in `default=1` is evaluated when you call `parser.add_argument`, where as the non-default value you pass as argument is evaluated at runtime, and therefore can be converted to float by argparse. It's not how argparse behaves; it's how python behaves in general. Consider this

```
def foo(x=1):
    # there is no way to tell the function body that you want 1.0
    # except for explicitly conversion
    # because 1 is passed by value, which has already been evaluated
    # and determined to be an int
    print (x/3)
```

**HUGE EDIT**: Ha, I understand your point now and I think it's reasonable. So I dig into the source code and looks what I found:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/argparse.py#l1984

So `argparse` DOES appear to make sure your default value is type compliant, so long as it's a string. Try:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--G', type=float, default='1', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.G / 3)
```

Not sure if that's a bug or a compromise...

Comment: That's my point. I think that for consistency, you should do something like `x = float(x)` inside `argparse`. Otherwise, the situation that I described above can lead to hard to catch errors.

Comment: Where of course, `float` refers to the type explicitly given in the `type=float` specification to `argparse`

Comment: @becko there you go! I understand you now. Updated!

Comment: The action on that line of `argparse` is very much intended.  Only string values are passed through the `type` *function*.  In this context `float` is a function that converts a string.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right - only string defaults are passed through the `type` function.  But there seems to be some reluctance to accept that logic.

Maybe this example will help:

```
import argparse
def mytype(astring):
    return '['+astring+']'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=mytype, default=1)
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=mytype, default='bar')
print parser.parse_args([])
print mytype(1)
```

produces:

```
0923:~/mypy$ python stack35429336.py 
Namespace(bar='[bar]', foo=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack35429336.py", line 8, in <module>
    print mytype(1)
  File "stack35429336.py", line 3, in mytype
    return '['+astring+']'
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I define a `type` function - it takes a string input, and returns something - anything that I want.  And raises an error if it can't return that.  Here I just append some characters to the string.

When the `default` is a string, it gets modified.  But when it is a number (not a string) it is inserted without change.  In fact as written `mytype` raises an error if given a number.

The `argparse` `type` is often confused with the function `type(a)`.  The latter returns values like `int`,`str`,`bool`.  Plus the most common examples are `int` and `float`.  But in `argparse` `float` is used as a function

```
float(x) -> floating point number
    Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.
```

`type=bool` is a common error.  [Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse).  `bool()` does not convert the string `'False'` to the boolean `False`.

```
In [50]: bool('False')
Out[50]: True
```

If `argparse` passed every default through the `type` function, it would be difficult to place values like `None` or `False` in the `namespace`.  No builtin function converts a string to `None`.

The key point is that the `type` parameter is a function (`callable`), not a casting operation or target.

For further clarification - or confusion - explore the `default` and `type` with `nargs=2` or `action='append'`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `type` is to sanitise and validate the arbitrary input you receive from the command line. It's a first line of defence against bogus input. There is no need to "defend" yourself against the `default` value, because that's the value *you* have decided on yourself and *you* are in power and have full control over your application. `type` does not mean that the resulting value after `parse_args()` must be that type; it means that any *input* should be that type/should be the result of that function.

What the *default value* is is completely independent of that and entirely up to you. It's completely conceivable to have a `default` value of `False`, and if a user inputs a number for this optional argument, then it'll be a number instead.

*Upgrading a comment below to be included here:* Python's philosophy includes "everyone is a responsible adult and Python won't overly question your decisions" (paraphrased). This very much applies here I think.

The fact that `argparse` does cast `default` *strings* could be explained by the fact that CLI input is always a string, and it's possible that you're chaining several argparsers, and the `default` value is set by a previous input. Anything that's not a string type however *must* have been explicitly chosen by you, so it won't be further mangled.

Comment: I beg to differ. Please see my answer. I found in argparse source code that it does try to make sure the default value is type-compliant.

Comment: ...to some extend it does. You can still use `False` as default value if you like (for example)...

Comment: So sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. That seems inconsistent. I think it would be simpler if it always converted to the explicit type.

Comment: @becko your best bet is to file a bug report and ask the author themselves. Not sure if that's intentional

Comment: IMO this at least partly goes back to Python's philosophy of "everyone is a responsible adult and Python won't overly question your decisions" (paraphrased). @becko The exception with strings *possibly* comes from the fact that CLI input is always a string type, and perhaps you're chaining a bunch of argparsers together and the default value could come from a previous argparse, while anything that's not a string must have been set by you explicitly already.

Comment: @deceze that sounds plausible :)

Answer (score 1):

If the default value is a string, the parser parses the value as if it were a command-line argument. In particular, the parser applies any type conversion argument, if provided, before setting the attribute on the Namespace return value. Otherwise, the parser uses the value as is:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--length', default='10', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--width', default=10.5, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here, `args.length` will be int 10 and `args.width` will be float 10.5, just as the default value.

The example is from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#default.

At first, I also have the same question. Then I notice this example, it explains the question pretty clearly.