# How to write boolean command line arguments with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to write an argument in an application where the argument that I am calling needs to be referenced on the first iteration/run of the script where the `initial_run` is set to `True`.  Otherwise this value should be left as false.  Now this parameter is configured in a configuration file.

The current code that I written is below.  What should be changed in this code to return the `True` value?  Now it only returns the value `False`.

```
import sys  
# main
param_1= sys.argv[0:] in (True, False)
print 'initial_run=', param_1
```

Comment: Command line arguments are always strings -- the entry point for a C program is specified as `int main(int argc, char* argv)`, and the `execv` family of syscalls takes arguments as an array of C strings. Since that's how the operating system hands them off, they can't possibly be anything else without being converted, parsed or casted.

Comment: You could use argparse(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse) which is a part of the standard library. Among third party libraries Click can be a good option(http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#boolean-flags).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Running the script from the command line:

```
# ./my_script.py true
```

The boolean can be obtined by doing:

```
import sys

initial_run = sys.argv[1].lower() == 'true'
```

This way we are doing a comparison of the first argument lowercased to be 'true', and the comparison will return boolean True if the strings match or boolean False if not.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
param_1 = sys.argv[0:] in (True, False)
```

to:

```
param_1 = eval(sys.argv[1])
assert isinstance(param_1, bool), raise TypeError('param should be a bool')
```

Comment: `bool` does not convert `"True"` and `"False"` to `True` and `False`. Calling `bool` on a string is equivalent to `len(string) != 0`.

Comment: Yes, I fixed this.

Comment: Suggest to avoid `eval`, it may have security implications. You may want to use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if may help,  what about using argparse?

```
import argparse

def read_cmdline():
    p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-c","--clear",type=bool, choices=[True,False],required=True)
    args=p.parse_args()
    return args 


if __name__=="__main__":
    args=read_cmdline()
    if args.clear:
        ###actions when clear is True
    else:
        ## actions when clear is False
```

Note the type=bool in add_argument