# Adding custom commandline parameters to run if elif in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse, execution

I need to add a commandline parameter to a python file (I don't have functions defined inside) so that the parameter would be platform, and then inside the file I need to use:

```
if platform == iphone:
    <execute some code>
elif platform == ipad:
    <execute some other code>
```

Basically whats defined under if and elif is the same code but using different resources (images, txt files, etc.). What I need is the possibility to run that file from commandline with the platform parameter like:

```
python somefile.py -iphone
```

Now I tried with argparse like that:

```
platform = argparse.ArgumentParser()
platform.add_argument("iphone")
platform.add_argument("ipad")
platform.parse_args()
```

But clearly it is wrong and/or is missing something because it doesn't work at all. I'm looking for a simplest possible way to achieve that.

Comment: platform is object (argumentParser object) not string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008806/6260170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass command as `python somefile.py iphone`
 then you can get the arguments passed in terminal with `sys.argv`.
It gives a list of arguments passed with command. In your case `sys.argv` will return **['somefile.py','iphone']** i.e 0th position will contain program name and from 1st place onwards all the arguments passed.

```
import sys

platform=sys.argv[1]

if platform == 'iphone':
    <execute some code>
elif platform == 'ipad':
    <execute some other code>
```

Comment: Ok, this one works, but I came up with another idea, if it is possible to add another argument that way, that would be passed into a variable. F.e. I run
 _python somefile.py -iphone -2.20.0_ so that the second parameter is version and is saved into a variable inside this file?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I did that :)
Second one would be:
version = sysargv[2] 
and I pass that variable/parameter to a function that puts that second parameter as string exactky where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ArgumentParser` you need to change your code to:

```
parser= argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-platform")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.platform == 'iphone'
    ##do something with that information
```

useage:

```
python somefile.py -platform iphone
```

read more about argParser [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

otherwise you could simply use `sys.argv[1]` :

```
import sys 
if sys.argv[1] == 'iphone':
    # iphone
```

useage for sys.argv:

```
python somefile.py iphone
```