# ArgumentParser: subparsers don't inherit registered types

Tags: python, argparse

We can add our own types to a parser's registry, for example:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from distutils.util import strtobool

parser = ArgumentParser('flats')
parser.register('type', 'boolean', strtobool)
parser.add_argument('--conveyor-belt', type='boolean')
```

This works so far, i.e. `args = parser.parse_args(['--conveyor-belt', 'on'])`   and then `args.conveyor_belt == True`.  But when trying to add subparser(s):

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparser = subparsers.add_parser('slaughterhouse')
subparser.add_argument('--rotating-knives', type='boolean')  # crash
```

We get error here: `ValueError 'boolean' is not callable`.

I want all subparsers to automatically inherit the types already registered by parent.  Possible?

Comment: Umm, I can't find any documentation about the `register` function in [the argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser). Are you sure you're not working with implementation details here?

Comment: Also, the [`type` argument docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) state that you may pass "any callable that takes a single string argument", but it never says that you can pass a string like `'boolean'` there.

Comment: I assume `ArgumentParser.register` is public interface and `ArgumentParser._registry_get` is non-public, because of the usual Python conventions.  Undocumented != implementation detail.  Happy to be convinced otherwise here, though.

Comment: I demonstrated the use of `register` here (in 2013): [Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse/19233287#19233287)

Comment: @hpaulj  I know you are very familiar with argparse.  Why do you think this thing is undocumented?  Non-public API, or documentation bug?

Comment: @wim, the documentation does not try to be a full, formal API. It's more of a common usage manual, a step beyond a tutorial.  It doesn't record all public classes and their methods.

Comment: Meh, there is also a usage manual/tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).  I think it's more a case that `argparse.py` is just a poorly maintained and poorly documented module.

Comment: When looking up some past bug/issues I realized that the `register` may need to be used when customizing the `_SubParsersAction` class.

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrated the use of `register` here, several years ago.

[Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse/19233287#19233287)

It isn't a hidden feature (i.e. no '_') but also not documented.

Each parser has a `registry` that matches strings with classes and functions.  If `action='store_true'`, the parser looks up 'store_true' in the `registry` and finds the corresponding `Action` subclass.

```
print(parser._registries)
```

`type` strings are also looked up, though as default only 'None' is registered.  Other common type values such as `int` and `float` are Python functions, and don't need to be registered.

Subparsers are new parsers, using the main parser class.  I don't think they use any of its `__init__` parameters, and certainly they don't use any attributes that might have been changed after creation.

It might be possible to define a `ArgumentParser` subclass that adds these items to the registry.

Some relevant parts of the `argparse.py` code:

```
def add_subparsers(self, **kwargs):

        # add the parser class to the arguments if it's not present
        kwargs.setdefault('parser_class', type(self))
        ...
        # create the parsers action and add it to the positionals list
        parsers_class = self._pop_action_class(kwargs, 'parsers')
        action = parsers_class(option_strings=[], **kwargs)
        ....

class _SubParsersAction(Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 prog,
                 parser_class,
                 dest=SUPPRESS,
                 help=None,
                 metavar=None):
        ...
        self._parser_class = parser_class
    def add_parser(self, name, **kwargs):
       ...
        parser = self._parser_class(**kwargs)
```

So the class of the main parser is recorded with the `subparsers` `Action` object., and that is used when creating the subparser.  But parameters like `description`, and `help_formatter` are taken from the `add_parser` command, not inherited.  There was a bug/issue asking for inheritance of the `formatter_class`, but no action.

---

From your code:

```
In [22]: parser._registries['type']
Out[22]: 
{None: <function argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__.<locals>.identity>,
 'boolean': <function distutils.util.strtobool>}
```

and

```
In [24]: subparser._registries['type']
Out[24]: {None: <function argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__.<locals>.identity>}
In [25]: subparser._registries['type'].update(parser._registries['type'])
In [27]: subparser.add_argument('--rotating-knives', type='boolean')  # crash
Out[27]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--rotating-knives'], dest='rotating_knives', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type='boolean', choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

or instead of `update`, simply share the dictionary:

```
subparser._registries = parser._registries
```

`argparse` does a lot of attribute sharing.  For example, the `_actions` list is shared between `parser` and all of its `action_groups`.

So if I were to add this to `argparse`, or my own version, I'd probably modify the `_SubParsersAction` class rather than the `ArgumentParser` class.   Either that, or just define a helper function:

```
   def new_parser(subparsers, *args, **kwargs):
       # parser - take from global
       sp = subparsers.add_parser(*args, **kwargs)
       sp._registries = parser._registries
       sp.help.formatter_class = parser.formatter_class
       etc
```

As best I can tell, `subparsers` does not have any reference to the main parser.  That is, `subparsers` is in the `parser._actions` list, but there's no link in the other direction.

### Changing subparsers Action class

`parser._defaults` is another attribute that isn't passed from main parser to subparsers.  It is set with `set_defaults`, which is documented:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults

Setting a different value in the subparsers is documented as a way of linking a function to the subparser:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers

Judging from questions here about subparsers, it is clear that the feature is quite useful.  But it is also a bit tricky to use, and not to everyone's liking.

One of the last patches that the original author, Steven J. Bethard, wrote had to do with passing the `Namespace` between main parser and subparsers.

[argparse set_defaults on subcommands should override top level set_defaults](https://bugs.python.org/issue9351)

But that wasn't to everyone's liking.

[argparse - subparsers does not retain namespace](https://bugs.python.org/issue27859)

In light of the current question, it interesting that I suggest using the `register` to use a customized `_SubParsersAction`.

> It uses a custom Action class (like your test case).  It subclasses ._SubParsersAction, and replaces the 9351 namespace use with the original one.  I use the registry to change the class that parser.add_subparsers() uses.

```
p.register('action', 'parsers', MyParserAction)
```

That's required because as the `add_subparsers` quote (above) shows, `argparse` uses the registry to determine what subclass to use.

One might argue that this use of `parser.register` needs to be documented.  But I don't see how it can be done without adding confusion to users who don't need the feature.