# python : argparse boolean arguments via command line

Tags: python, command-line, boolean, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to pass in arguments to this `sampleCode.py` file.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', '-n', default=2, type=int)
parser.add_argument('--directory', default='/some/string/')
parser.add_argument('--exclude_hydro', default=False, action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.num_epochs)    # 2
print(args.exclude_hydro) # False
```

The following commands work for int and string arguments, but not for boolean.

```
$python3 sampleCode.py -n3                      #args.num_epochs=3
$python3 sampleCode.py --num_epochs 3           #args.num_epochs=3
$python3 sampleCode.py --directory /new/string  #args.directory = /new/string
$python3 sampleCode.py --exclude_hydro True     #error
```

**How can I pass in boolean arguments?** I have tried `type=bool` as a parameter for `.add_argument()` but that doesn't work.

Comment: looks like dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse

Comment: What does `bool('False')` produce?

Answer (score -1):

`parser.add_argument('--exclude-hydro', const=True)` should work.

Note that you should also be defining `help="<help_text>"` so that when a user calls the application without any arguments, help text is displayed describing the purpose of each argument:

`parser.add_argument('--exclude-hydro', const=True, help="<help_text>")`

Comment: `const` isn't accepted as a parameter unless `nargs='?'` or `action='store_const'`.  In both cases you also want a `default`.