# Understanding the difference between import X and from X.Y import Z

Tags: python

This is very basic question which has a very extensive answer written by @Mark Roddy
[Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

According to this answer there are pros and cons to each method but the result is equivalent and both work.

so doing:

```
import module
```

or

```
from module import foo
```

should work.

**My Question:**

Consider this example:

```
import distutils
print (distutils.util.strtobool('true'))
```

Which gives:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module> AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'util'
```

And:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
print (strtobool('true'))
```

Which gives following ouput:

```
1
```

So I'm confused. Both should work. Why Python generates an exception for the first approach?

Comment: try with `import distutils.util` then `print( distutils.util.strtobool )` ?

Comment: @barny This isn't a code to solve. Note that what you suggested is what I did which returned 1 - it's OK. I'm asking why the first one raised exception

Comment: because at that point you haven't imported distutils.util

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `import A`, and then try to access `A.B`, then `B` must be a valid attribute present in module `A`. For instance:

```
# A.py
from . import B
# or
B = 'foo'
```

If `A` contains the above code, then inside `A`, `B` is a valid local name and by extension an accessible attribute of module `A`. However, if module `A` does not define any `B`, then you can't access it when you `import A`.

Now, `import A.B` or `from A.B import ...` explicitly looks not at the attributes of the modules, but at the files and folders. So even if inside `A.py` there's no symbol `B` defined, as long as there's a file `B.py` or folder `B`, `import` will import it.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should be also added to the refereed question. This is important information which is missing there

Answer (score 3):

These are equivalent:

```
from mod import val
val

import mod
mod.val
```

As are these:

```
from mod1.mod2 import val
val

import mod1.mod2
mod1.mod2.val
```

But this doesn't work, as `mod2` is not imported:

```
import mod1
mod1.mod2.val
```

If you add `import mod2` inside `mod1.py` (or `mod1/__init__.py`), then `mod2` becomes a value exported by `mod1`, and the last example will work. `distutils` does not import `distutils.util`, so you have to import it yourself in order to gain access to its exported members.