# Luigi: Is there a way to pass 'false' to a bool parameter from the command line?

Tags: python, terminal, luigi

I have a `Luigi` task with a boolean parameter that is set to **True** by default:

```
class MyLuigiTask(luigi.Task):
    my_bool_param = luigi.BoolParameter(default=True)
```

When I run this task from terminal, I sometimes want to pass that parameter as **False**, but get the following result:

```
$ MyLuigiTask --my_bool_param False
error: unrecognized arguments: False
```

Same obviously for `false` and `0`...

I understand that I can make the default **False** and then use the flag `--my_bool_param` if I want to make it **True**, but I much prefer to have the default **True**.

Is there any way to do this, and still pass **False** from terminal?

Comment: Seems this is answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse

Comment: Would making a flag called `no-my-param` be okay for you?

Comment: @Tom Your reference is for argparse, not for Luigi.  Are you suggesting they have the exact same mechanism?

Comment: @SimonCrane thanks for the suggestion, it is "ok" the same as making the default False is ok. I am wondering though if there is something I am missing with passing "False" to Luigi...

Comment: Ah I see. Here is the answer: https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/193#issuecomment-25854409
or you override the cmdline_parser:
https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/cmdline_parser.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution in [Luigi docs](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.html#luigi.BoolParameter):

```
class MyLuigiTask(luigi.Task):
    my_bool_param = luigi.BoolParameter(
        default=True, 
        parsing=luigi.BoolParameter.EXPLICIT_PARSING)

    def run(self):
        print(self.my_bool_param)
```

Here `EXPLICIT_PARSING` tell Luigi that adding the flag `--my_bool_param false` in the terminal call to `MyLuigiTask`, will be parsed as `store_false`.

Now we can have:

```
$ MyLuigiTask --my_bool_param false
False
```