# Argparse not parsing boolean arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, argparse

I am trying to make a build script like this:

```
import glob
import os
import subprocess
import re
import argparse
import shutil

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build project')

    parser.add_argument('--clean_logs', type=bool, default=True,
                        help='If true, old debug logs will be deleted.')

    parser.add_argument('--run', type=bool, default=True,
                        help="If true, executable will run after compilation.")

    parser.add_argument('--clean_build', type=bool, default=False,
                        help="If true, all generated files will be deleted and the"
                        " directory will be reset to a pristine condition.")

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    parser = create_parser()
    print(parser)
```

However no matter how I try to pass the argument I only get the default values. I always get `Namespace(clean_build=False, clean_logs=True, run=True)`.

I have tried:

```
python3 build.py --run False
python3 build.py --run=FALSE
python3 build.py --run FALSE
python3 build.py --run=False
python3 build.py --run false
python3 build.py --run 'False'
```

It's always the same thing. What am I missing?

Comment: We use `action="store_true"` to deal with this kind of problem: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing boolean values with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse)

Comment: @IdeaO. No that answer does not explain why arparse isn;t parsing the input. My question is different.

Comment: Try `bool("False")` or `bool("FALSE")`.  The only string that returns `False` is `bool("")`.  You have to write your own function that recognizes strings like 'False' or 'No' as `False`.  The builtin `bool` does not do that for you.

Comment: An old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how the `argparse` understands the boolean arguments.

Basically you should use `action='store_true'` or `action='store_false'` instead of the default value, with the understanding that not specifying the argument will give you the opposite of the action, e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('-x', type=bool, action='store_true')
```

will cause:

```
python3 command -x
```

to have `x` set to `True` and

```
python3 command
```

to have `x` set to `False`.

While `action=store_false` will do the opposite.

---

Setting `bool` as type does not behave as you expect and this is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue14392).

The reason for the current behavior is that `type` is expected to be a callable which is used as `argument = type(argument)`. `bool('False')` evaluates to `True`, so you need to set a different `type` for the behavior you expect to happen.

Comment: A more recent bug/issue  https://bugs.python.org/issue37564 found that distutils.util.strtobool can parse a variety of yes/no (English only) words to True/False values.

Comment: I had to remove the "type" argument to make it work. Like this: ```parser.add_argument("-Var1", action="store_true")``` since ```parser.add_argument("-Var1", type=bool, action="store_true")``` caused an error.

Answer (score 5):

Argument `run` is initialized to `True` even that you pass `--run False`

Below code based on this [great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357954/1264304) answer is workaround around this issue:

```
import argparse

def str2bool(v):
    if isinstance(v, bool):
        return v
    if v.lower() in ('yes', 'true', 't', 'y', '1'):
        return True
    elif v.lower() in ('no', 'false', 'f', 'n', '0'):
        return False
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Boolean value expected.')

def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # List of args
    ap.add_argument('--foo', type=str2bool, help='Some helpful text')
    # Importable object
    args = ap.parse_args()
    print(args.foo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```