# Python argv "False, false' are recognized as True

Tags: python, parsing, boolean, argparse

I ran my program using the below line

```
python ***.py --if_normalize False
```

but my program recognizes `if_normalize` variable to be `True`

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--work-path", required=True, type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--seed", default=42, type=int, help="Random seed")
    parser.add_argument("--batch-size", default=128, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--attack", default='no', type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--gpu",default=2, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--if_normalize', default=False, type=bool)
    return parser.parse_args()

args = parse_args()
print(args)
```

and it prints if_normalize is True

I passed 'False, false, -1' but still it recognizes as `True`

Comment: WIth `argparse` it's typical to use the parameter as "exists or not" rather than is True/False. So `parser.add_argument('--normalize', action='store_true')` is more appropriate. And it's either given as a parameter when running the script (`True`) or it's not given at all (`False`). Or in reverse with `action='store_false'`. If you really do want it as `--if_normalize True/False`, then [see the top 3 answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15008758/1431750).

Answer (score 4):

Because it just runs the input through `bool`, and `bool('False')` is `True`, because any non-empty string is truthy.

You'd usually do this by using a *flag* instead:

```
parser.add_argument('--if-normalize', action='store_true')
```

The `store_true` action implies a default of `False`, and sets it to `True` if the flag is present. I.e. you'd use it like:

```
$ python ***.py --if-normalize
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change to the following:

```
parser.add_argument('--if_normalize', action='store_true')
```

This will set the argument `if_normalize` to `True` when you add it to the command line arguments when calling to your script.

You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and see exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

> The bool() function is not recommended as a type converter. All it does is convert empty strings to False and non-empty strings to True. This is usually not what is desired.

This `type` section was recently expanded in an attempt to remove some common misunderstandings, including this misuse of the `bool` (a builtin) function.

You could write your own function that parses a whole slew of 'yes/no' words.  Developers have declined to do so because there are too many alternatives, especially if non-English possibilities are included.

The `store_true` `Action` is enough for most purposes.