# Python not receiving pyshell.send message... sometimes

Tags: javascript, python

So I am making a magic mirror. Ive made it so i can turn the screen off with my Alexa device, but i also want to stop the face recognition module from using the camera when the screen is off.  When i use python.send() like this it works.

```
    /* Magic Mirror
     * Module: MMM-Face-Reco-DNN
     *
     * By Thierry Nischelwitzer http://nischi.ch
     * MIT Licensed.
     */
    
    // 'use strict';
    const NodeHelper = require('node_helper');
    const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
    const onExit = require('signal-exit');
    var pythonStarted = false;
    
    module.exports = NodeHelper.create({
      onoff: 'on',
      python_start: function() {
        const self = this;
        const extendedDataset = this.config.extendDataset ? 'True' : 'False';
        const options = {
          mode: 'json',
          stderrParser: line => JSON.stringify(line),
          args: [
            '--cascade=' + this.config.cascade,
            '--encodings=' + this.config.encodings,
            '--usePiCamera=' + this.config.usePiCamera,
            '--source=' + this.config.source,
            '--rotateCamera=' + this.config.rotateCamera,
            '--method=' + this.config.method,
            '--detectionMethod=' + this.config.detectionMethod,
            '--interval=' + this.config.checkInterval,
            '--output=' + this.config.output,
            '--extendDataset=' + extendedDataset,
            '--dataset=' + this.config.dataset,
            '--tolerance=' + this.config.tolerance,
          ],
        
        };
    
        if (this.config.pythonPath != null && this.config.pythonPath !== '') {
          options.pythonPath = this.config.pythonPath;
        };
    
        // Start face reco script
        const pyshell = new PythonShell(
          'modules/' + this.name + '/tools/facerecognition.py',
          options
        );
        // check if a message of the python script is comming in
    

        // Send message to hault face-recognition loop
        pyshell.send({control: "off"}).end()    

        pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    
        
          // A status message has received and will log
          if (message.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
            console.log('[' + self.name + '] ' + message.status);
          }
    
          // Somebody new are in front of the camera, send it back to the Magic Mirror Module
          if (message.hasOwnProperty('login')) {
            console.log('[' + self.name + '] ' + 'Users ' + message.login.names.join(' - ') + ' logged in.');
            self.sendSocketNotification('user', {action: 'login', users: message.login.names,});
          }
    
          // Somebody left the camera, send it back to the Magic Mirror Module
          if (message.hasOwnProperty('logout')) {
            console.log('[' + self.name + '] ' + 'Users ' + message.logout.names.join(' - ') + ' logged out.');
            self.sendSocketNotification('user', {action: 'logout', users: message.logout.names,});
          }
        })
    
        
    
        // Shutdown node helper
        pyshell.end(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('[' + self.name + '] ' + 'finished running...');
        });
    
        onExit(function(code, signal) {
          self.destroy();
        });
      },
      
      python_stop: function(){
        module.exports.onoff = 'off';
      },
      
      destroy: function() {
        console.log('[' + this.name + '] ' + 'Terminate python');
      },
    
      socketNotificationReceived: function(notification, payload) {
        // Configuration are received
        if (notification === 'CONFIG') {
          this.config = payload;
          // Set static output to 0, because we do not need any output for MMM
          this.config.output = 0;
          if (!pythonStarted) {
            pythonStarted = true;
            this.python_start();
          }
        }
        // added
        // receive notification from mmm-face-reco-dnn.js to stop or start
        // the python script
        if (notification === "START_STOP"){
          if (payload == 'off'){
            this.python_stop();
          } else {
            this.python_start();
          }
        }
      },
    
      stop: function() {
        pythonStarted = false;
        this.python_stop();
      },
    });
```

This is the python code:

```
# USAGE
# python pi_face_recognition.py --cascade haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml --encodings encodings.pickle

# import the necessary packages
from distutils.log import error
from ossaudiodev import control_names
from imutils.video import FPS, VideoStream
from datetime import datetime
import face_recognition
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import time
import cv2
import json
import sys
import signal
import os
import numpy as np

# added to control loop at the end
loop_on = True

# To properly pass JSON.stringify()ed bool command line parameters, e.g. "--extendDataset"
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse
def str2bool(v):
    if isinstance(v, bool):
       return v
    if v.lower() in ('yes', 'true', 't', 'y', '1'):
        return True
    elif v.lower() in ('no', 'false', 'f', 'n', '0'):
        return False
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Boolean value expected.')

def printjson(type, message):
    print(json.dumps({type: message}))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def signalHandler(signal, frame):
    global closeSafe
    closeSafe = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signalHandler)
closeSafe = False

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--cascade", type=str, required=False, default="haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml",
    help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", type=str, required=False, default="encodings.pickle",
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--usePiCamera", type=int, required=False, default=1,
    help="Is using picamera or builtin/usb cam")
ap.add_argument("-s", "--source", required=False, default=0,
    help="Use 0 for /dev/video0 or 'http://link.to/stream'")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--rotateCamera", type=int, required=False, default=0,
    help="rotate camera")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--method", type=str, required=False, default="dnn",
    help="method to detect faces (dnn, haar)")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detectionMethod", type=str, required=False, default="hog",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--interval", type=int, required=False, default=2000,
    help="interval between recognitions")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=int, required=False, default=1,
    help="Show output")
ap.add_argument("-eds", "--extendDataset", type=str2bool, required=False, default=False,
    help="Extend Dataset with unknown pictures")
ap.add_argument("-ds", "--dataset", required=False, default="../dataset/",
    help="path to input directory of faces + images")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tolerance", type=float, required=False, default=0.6,
    help="How much distance between faces to consider it a match. Lower is more strict.")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the known faces and embeddings along with OpenCV's Haar
# cascade for face detection
printjson("status", "loading encodings + face detector...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(args["cascade"])

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
printjson("status", "starting video stream...")

if args["source"].isdigit():
    src = int(args["source"])
else:
    src = args["source"]

if args["usePiCamera"] >= 1:
    vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True, rotation=args["rotateCamera"]).start()
else:
    vs = VideoStream(src=src).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# variable for prev names
prevNames = []

# create unknown path if needed
if args["extendDataset"] is True:
    unknownPath = os.path.dirname(args["dataset"] + "unknown/")
    try:
            os.stat(unknownPath)
    except:
            os.mkdir(unknownPath)

tolerance = float(args["tolerance"])

# start the FPS counter
fps = FPS().start()

# loop over frames from the video file stream
while loop_on:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to 500px (to speedup processing)
    originalFrame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(originalFrame, width=500)

    try:
        printjson('status', 'looping')
        for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
            printjson('status', 'got here')
            control_message = json.loads(line)['control']
            printjson('status', control_message)
            if control_message == "off":
                vs.stop()
                loop_on = False
        if control_message == "off":
            break
    except:
        pass

    if args["method"] == "dnn":
        # load the input image and convert it from BGR (OpenCV ordering)
        # to dlib ordering (RGB)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes
        # corresponding to each face in the input image
        boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
            model=args["detectionMethod"])
    elif args["method"] == "haar":
        # convert the input frame from (1) BGR to grayscale (for face
        # detection) and (2) from BGR to RGB (for face recognition)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # detect faces in the grayscale frame
        rects = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

        # OpenCV returns bounding box coordinates in (x, y, w, h) order
        # but we need them in (top, right, bottom, left) order, so we
        # need to do a bit of reordering
        boxes = [(y, x + w, y + h, x) for (x, y, w, h) in rects]

    # compute the facial embeddings for each face bounding box
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    names = []

    # loop over the facial embeddings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # compute distances between this encoding and the faces in dataset
        distances = face_recognition.face_distance(data["encodings"], encoding)

        minDistance = 1.0
        if len(distances) > 0:
            # the smallest distance is the closest to the encoding
            minDistance = min(distances)

        # save the name if the distance is below the tolerance
        if minDistance < tolerance:
            idx = np.where(distances == minDistance)[0][0]
            name = data["names"][idx]
        else:
            name = "unknown"

        # update the list of names
        names.append(name)

    # loop over the recognized faces
    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        # draw the predicted face name on the image
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 0), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        txt = name + " (" + "{:.2f}".format(minDistance) + ")"
        cv2.putText(frame, txt, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # display the image to our screen
    if (args["output"] == 1):
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    # update the FPS counter
    fps.update()

    logins = []
    logouts = []
    # Check which names are new login and which are new logout with prevNames
    for n in names:
        if (prevNames.__contains__(n) == False and n is not None):
            logins.append(n)

            # if extendDataset is active we need to save the picture
            if args["extendDataset"] is True:
                # set correct path to the dataset
                path = os.path.dirname(args["dataset"] + '/' + n + '/')

                today = datetime.now()
                cv2.imwrite(path + '/' + n + '_' + today.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + '.jpg', originalFrame)
    for n in prevNames:
        if (names.__contains__(n) == False and n is not None):
            logouts.append(n)

    # send inforrmation to prompt, only if something has changes
    if (logins.__len__() > 0):
        printjson("login", {
            "names": logins
        })

    if (logouts.__len__() > 0):
        printjson("logout", {
            "names": logouts
        })

    # set this names as new prev names for next iteration
    prevNames = names

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q") or closeSafe == True:
        break

    time.sleep(args["interval"] / 1000)

# stop the timer and display FPS information
fps.stop()
printjson("status", "elasped time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
printjson("status", "approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

I put the send command inside of the pyshell.on() section and that worked once, but now I cant replicate.  Im trying to change the value of onoff with an Alexa command, which I can do.  But I need to be able to send the stop command after doing so.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging I learned that stdout does not write until the program has "free time", so I tried the following:

```
if(module.exports.onoff == "off"){
    pyshell.send({control: "off"});
    pyshell.childProcess.kill()
  }
```

This worked for my situation.

EDIT: So upon restarting the process would end again.  Im assuming because it actually read the stdin on the other end.  But I noticed that the camera would turn off after executing pyshell.childProces.kill().  So I removed pyshell.send().  This is what I have now:

```
  if(module.exports.onoff == "off"){
    pyshell.childProcess.kill()
  }
```

And earlier on in the code I reset module.exports.onoff to "on" like this:

```
    module.exports["onoff"] = "on";
```

So NOW it's working like I want it to.

EDIT: AGAIN: Not sure what happened but that stopped working.  So I put the send() back in and now it works again.

Comment: This did work to turn off my webcam.  But when I try to restart the process it ends before turning the camera back on.  So a little more tinkering is in order.