# How to add arguments to Python script entrypoint based on conditions

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have an entry point like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ,"/usr/local/bin/script.py" ]
```

I want to be able to add multiple arguments to script.py if a particular container has "MY_ENV_VAR" set to TRUE.

So for instance if:

```
MY_ENV_VAR = true
MY_ENV_VAR2 = true
MY_ENV_VAR3 = false (or anything other than true)
```

I want to run
`/usr/local/bin/script.py --my-env-var --my-env-var2`

I can't find a good working example of how to accomplish this

Comment: You can't configure the ENTRYPOINT to change according to whether an env var is present or not, but you can make it so that the `script.py` prompts you with the right options by using argparse properly

Comment: Another approach would be to-- use the ENV inside your script.py and do conditional stmt based on ENV.

Comment: [Setting options from environment variables when using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551117/setting-options-from-environment-variables-when-using-argparse) describes a generic approach for doing this (setting `default=os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR']` for each option in your `argparse` configuration); this will translate just fine to Docker without changing anything.  Does that setup work for you?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to conditionally do this within the Dockerfile, but you can achieve the desired behavior by configuring the Python script `script.py` as follows:

```
import argparse
import os

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Arguments")

    if os.environ.get("MY_ENV_VAR") is not None:
        parser.add_argument("--my-env-var", required=True, action="store_true")
    
    if os.environ.get("MY_ENV_VAR2") is not None:
        parser.add_argument("--my-env-var2", required=True, action="store_true")
    
    parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The logic is that if `MY_ENV_VAR` or `MY_ENV_VAR2`, then a required argparse argument is set.