# Parse arguments to get an argument value, or environment variable value, and raise exception if neither

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I wish to use the `argparse` module to set the value of a server URL. As well as being set via an argument, the vale can also be in an environment variable, though the argument should always take precedence.

To achieve this, I've added an argument to the parser with the environment variable value as the default, and a custom type. However, if the argument is omitted, the custom `type=EnvironDefault` is not initialised. This means that if default value is `None`, that value is used regardless, rather than an exception being raised as expected.

I have found a [10 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551117/setting-options-from-environment-variables-when-using-argparse) that suggests it is necessary to check the value of the argument after parsing the arguments, but I'm hoping that in the interim a solution has been added to `argparse`.

#### Example 1 - Success - Environment variable but no argument

```bash
foo@bar:~$ export SERVER_URL="https://some.server.co.uk"
foo@bar:~$ python mycli
Namespace(url='https://some.server.co.uk')
```

#### Example 2 - Success - Environment variable and argument

```bash
foo@bar:~$ export SERVER_URL="https://some.server.co.uk"
foo@bar:~$ python mycli --url "https://different.server.co.uk"
Namespace(url='https://different.server.co.uk')
```

#### Example 3 - Failure - No environment variable or argument

```bash
foo@bar:~$ unset SERVER_URL
foo@bar:~$ python mycli
Namespace(url=None)
```

##### Expected response

```bash
usage: mycli [-h] [--url URL]
mycli: error: argument --url: Server URL must be provided via either the CLI or the environment variable SERVER_URL.
```

---

## Example Argument Parser

```py
import argparse
import os

class EnvironDefault(str):

    def __init__(self, url: str) -> None:
        err_msg = (
            'Server URL must be provided via either the CLI or the '
            'environment variable SERVER_URL.')
        if not url:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(err_msg)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--url', type=EnvironDefault, default=os.environ.get('SERVER_URL'),
    help='Server URL. Overrides environment variable SERVER_URL.')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Default argument values are assigned directly to the destination, not passed to the type first. Since you won't know if no argument is provided until after parsing is done, you'll have to either override `ArgumentParser.parse_args`, or content yourself with checking the return value of `parse_args`.

Comment: (Or dynamically decide if the argument is required or not; see my answer below.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Your answer below has steered me straight, so thanks for that. However, I'm curious about your suggestion of overriding `ArgumentParser.parse_args` - presumably I'd have to dig further into the `ArgumentParser` object, as it doesn't look like there is anything in `parse_args` that I can override to pass the default value to the type first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the program starts, you can check immediately if `SERVER_URL` is available, and use that fact to decide if `--url` is required or not.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--url', required='SERVER_URL' not in os.environ, default=os.environ.get('SERVER_URL'),
    help='Server URL. Overrides environment variable SERVER_URL.')
    
print(parser.parse_args())
```

If `SERVER_URL` is *not* in the environment, the default value of `None` will be ignored, because `--url` is required. If it is in the environment, then the default value will be used.

Note that default values are *not* processed by your type. If you do use a custom type, it should be applied to the default explicitly. For example -

```py
parser.add_argument('--value', 
                    required='VALUE' not in os.environ,                               
                    type=int,
                    default=int(os.environ.get('VALUE')))
```

Comment: It's not something I've used in the past to solve this problem--just thought of it now--so there might be some issues I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Both of your suggestions here work, so thanks for that. The only thing of note is that on your second suggestion (explicitly applying the type to the default), the `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` exception is caught outside of `argparse`, so you don't get the nicely formatted error with the usage.

Comment: True, but it's really "your" responsibility (not `argparse`'s) to ensure that the default value is correct.

Comment: Agreed, just mentioning it for prosperity in case others stumble across this.