# What does "@" at the command line mean?

Tags: unix, command-line, cat

What is the effect of putting "@" before something (like the path of a file containing classpath entries for a Java run command)?

I know it's something to do with file contents but as you can imagine trying to search for it on Google is a bit difficult. I can't locate a manpage that talks about it either.

Comment: I think it means 'read the file nominated by this name (each line in the named file represents an entry)' instead of 'this is the entry'.

Comment: The tags suggest you are talking about the unix shell, the text suggests java. Please clarify. And please provide an example, even if it's cluttered.

Comment: @Marian it looks like he wants to run java program from command line, and he has "@" character in parameter for that java program.

Comment: I definitely don't think it's java-specific, that's just the most easy-to-explain example I know. Since I don't understand what it does, I'm having trouble reducing it to a bare-bones example (and obfuscating any information that is company-secret). Also, I don't have the example command where it works available at the moment, it's just from memory. I'm actually trying to see if I can use the '@' symbol to perform a different task.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler stated correctly "...each line ... represents an entry", you can collect Java command line arguments in a file and add them when starting a java app, e.g., java @path_to_arguments/args.txt my.app.Main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can mean different things in different programs. As a convention @file at command-line could be interpreted as:

> Read command-line options from file. The options read are inserted in
>   place of the original @file option. If file does not exist, or cannot
>   be read, then the option will be treated literally, and not removed.
>   Options in file are separated by whitespace. A whitespace character
>   may be included in an option by surrounding the entire option in
>   either single or double quotes. Any character (including a backslash)
>   may be included by prefixing the character to be included with a
>   backslash. The file may itself contain additional @file options; any
>   such options will be processed recursively.
>   [from `ld` docs for @file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)

Answer (score 2):

The `@` character has no general meaning on the Unix command line. It has uses by some popular utilities. A command that begins with `@` in a `Makefile` tells `make` not to echo the line before executing it. GNU Autoconf will substitute `@`-enclosed variables, such as `@srcdir@`, with their substitutions discovered by `configure`.

Comment: Oh, so it depends on the shell you're using?

Comment: What you seem to describe is not a shell thing at all.

Comment: So where would it come from in the case of java running? I doubt it comes from the java binary.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may
>   only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> (...)
>
> @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).
>
> (...)

You can use @ (at-sign) in parameter for any program without escaping.

If you have to pass something like this `$@` in parameter - you have to escape only `$` (dollar sign).

Comment: I've also seen @$someVar . Is that completely unrelated?

Comment: No idea. Anyway, you can use it in your script/command. It does not require escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Python argparse also has built-in support for `@opts.txt` to take CLI options from the file `opts.txt` if enabled with the `fromfile_prefix_chars` option: [Which is the best way to allow configuration options be overridden at the command line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609852/which-is-the-best-way-to-allow-configuration-options-be-overridden-at-the-comman/52029634#52029634) The syntax is so insane however, with its potential for conflicts with an actual file named `@myfile` that it is seldom used. Saner version of it asked at: [how to get argparse to read arguments from a file with an option rather than prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433316/how-to-get-argparse-to-read-arguments-from-a-file-with-an-option-rather-than-pre)