# How to get argparse to read arguments from a file with an option after positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to be able to put command-line arguments in a file, and then pass them to a python program, with argparse, using an option rather than a prefix character, for instance:

`$ python myprogram.py 1 2 --foo 1 -A somefile.txt --bar 2`

This is almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433316/how-to-get-argparse-to-read-arguments-from-a-file-with-an-option-rather-than-pre), except that I need to have some positional arguments at the start; when that solution calls `parse_args`, it fails if the file does not have the positional arguments in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `somefile.txt` contains

```
one
two
three
```

then

```
$ python myprogram.py 1 2 --foo 1 @somefile.txt --bar 2
```

using the `prefix char` is effectively the same as

```
$ python myprogram.py 1 2 --foo 1 one two three --bar 2
```

In other words, right at the start of parsing, the @ file is read, and its contents are spliced into the `argv` list.  From there parsing occurs normally.

One thing I suggested in the other SO question was to implement that splicing yourself, prior to parsing.

The answer that you are referring to uses a `custom` Action; at the point where the usual `Action` just places the `value` in the `namespace`, this action reads and parses the file:

```
parser.parse_args(f.read().split(), namespace)
```

A variant parses into a new `namespace` and selectively copies values to the main `namespace`.

Apparently your problem is that your parser has some required arguments, and this `parse_args` raises an error if the file does not contain those.  That's not surprising.

One solution is to use a different `parser` for this file, one that is designed to work with just the content of the file.  I would just define it globally.

```
alt_parser.parse_args(f.read().split(), namespace)
```

In other words, you don't have to use the `parser` that was passed in as a parameter.

A variation on this is to put the filename in the namespace, and handle it after the first parsing:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.A:
    argv = open(args.A).read().split()
    args1 = alt_parser.parse_args(argv)
```

But you might ask, can't we tell what arguments have already been parsed, and take that into account in handling `-A`?  The `parser` is not a state-machine; parsing does not alter any of its attributes.  The only variable that reflects parsing so far is the `namespace`.  All other parsing variables are local to the calling code.

Comment: Should have said: `@` does just the right thing, but I am copying behavior of another program.  This makes sense; now the trick is making a second parser with the same arguments except without the required, positional ones.

Comment: You could make that parser first, and use it as a `parents` to the main one.  Then you just have to add the `positionals` to the `child`.