# Best way to pass command line arguments via file in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a lot of arguments to pass to my `main.py`. It's easier to store them in a txt file. So, i would like to know best way of using "config" files to pass CL args.
Shell script is not what i need, unfortunatly.

Comment: ... Other than a shell script?

Comment: How is your current `main.py` parsing its args?

Comment: @Robᵩ I don't know yet. I'am able to implement it as i need it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433316/how-to-get-argparse-to-read-arguments-from-a-file-with-an-option-rather-than-pre

Comment: Even more related: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), then [`fromfile_prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) is designed to solve exactly this problem.

In your launching program, put all of the arguments, one per line, into a file. Pass `@file.txt` to your child program. In your child program, pass a `fromfile_prefix_chars` parameter to the `ArgumentParser()` constructor:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
```

`argparse` takes care of the rest for you.

Here is an example:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')
parser.add_argument('q', nargs='*')

ns = parser.parse_args()
print(ns)
```

The contents of `foo.txt`:

```
-f
1
--bar=2
q one
q two
```

The command line and the output:

```
$ python zz.py @foo.txt
Namespace(bar='2', foo='1', q=['q one', 'q two'])
```

Comment: actually, i have been expecting diffuculties when putting more than one arg in the file. Can you please give an example of a file and argument parsing with 2 arguments

Comment: I've added an example. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use [configparser.](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html)  It uses .ini files and it's really easy to use.

Config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
KeepAlive = 45
ForwardX11 = yes
```

Example Code:

```
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.sections()
[]
>>> config.read('example.ini')
>>> for key in config['bitbucket.org']: print(key)
...
keepalive
forwardx11
>>> default = config['default']
>>> default['keepalive']
'45'
>>> default['ForwardX11']
'yes'
```

Comment: That's very good. But i expected something more simple and beautiful, anyway

Comment: You should add a direct answer in here, as the content of link could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that converts any `@foo` argument into the contents of `foo`, one argument per line. After the conversion, you may use `sys.argv` in any of the normal ways.

```
import sys

def expand_arg_files(args):
    for arg in args:
       if arg.startswith('@'):
           with open(arg[1:]) as f:
               file_args = f.read().splitlines()
           yield from expand_arg_files(file_args)
       else:
           yield arg


sys.argv[:] = expand_arg_files(sys.argv[:])
print(sys.argv)
```

Notes:

- The generator delegation syntax requires Python3.3 or higher.
- You may have `@` args inside the argument file. The expansion is recursive.