# Argparse TypeError for count-type argument when default value is provided

Tags: python, arguments, runtime-error, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm writing flexible configuration module for my Python application. I want to allow configuration options be overridden at the command line in Python. To do that I'm following the idea provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609852/which-is-the-best-way-to-allow-configuration-options-be-overridden-at-the-comman) using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html) module.

Unfortunately, I came across unexpected exception in some particular use case. See the following (very [simplified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)) code – let's call it `/tmp/test.py`:

```
import argparse
import configparser

# App's default settings

defaults = {
    'verbose': 3,
    'foo': 'bar'
}

# Parser for reading configuration file path (if provided)

first_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    add_help=False)
first_parser.add_argument('-c', '--conf', metavar='FILE', help='Config file')
args, remaining_argv = first_parser.parse_known_args()

if args.conf:
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(args.conf)
    options = dict(parser.items('defaults'))
    defaults.update(options)

# Parser for reading app's verbosity level and value for --foo option

second_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[first_parser], add_help=False)
second_parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='count', default=0)
second_parser.add_argument('--foo', default='xyz')
second_parser.set_defaults(**defaults)
config = second_parser.parse_args(remaining_argv)

print(config)
```

The problem:

```
me@mycomp:/tmp$ python3 /tmp/test.py
Namespace(conf=None, foo='bar', verbose=3)

me@mycomp:/tmp$ python3 /tmp/test.py -v
Namespace(conf=None, foo='bar', verbose=4)

me@mycomp:/tmp$ python3 /tmp/test.py --conf /tmp/config
Namespace(conf=None, foo="aaa", verbose='6')

me@mycomp:/tmp$ python3 /tmp/test.py -v --conf /tmp/config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    config = second_parser.parse_args(remaining_argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1735, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1767, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/libPotwor/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1973, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1913, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1841, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1006, in __call__
    new_count = _ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, 0) + 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

`/tmp/config` content:

```
me@mycomp:/tmp$ cat /tmp/config
[defaults]
verbose = 6
foo = aaa
```

What's the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: The `count` action fetches the default value, adds 1, and puts it back in the Namespace.  It looks like ConfigParser is putting a string '6' in the default, as shown in the config example without '-v'.   It's choking on `"6"+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **options = dict(parser.items('defaults'))** -> options can be [('your_key', int_your_value)].
You should edit: {'your_key': int}

Docs : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm

Comment: I don't understand your explanation, but I guess that you mean that value corresponding to the `verbose` key needs to be [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int) (**not** [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html), as it's now). That's right. That fixed the problem. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry. My english is not good so my explanation is not clear.
I'm trying to improve it.